# Limiting size of database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I currently have an environment of MongoDB, including Shards and Replicat Sets.
I was wondering if there is any way to limit the size of a database. I've read that I can limit the size with the --quota parameter, but this would globally limit the size of all the databases, while I'm trying to limit the size of certain databases to differnet sizes.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use capped collection, which is applicable per collection within the database.
Refer to sample on MongoDB's doc http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 5000 } )

Where "log" is the collection name.

Do consider that in a capped collection, oldest document gets overwritten by new inserted document.

Comment: Well, capped collections isn't what I'm looking for, I want to limit the size on a database level rather than a collection level